# PHP binding 'bigint' datatype (MySQLi prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$studentId = 57004542323382
$companyOfferId = 7

$sql = 'INSERT INTO studentPlacement (companyOfferId, studentId) VALUES (?, ?)';

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $offerId, $studentId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $insertId = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

My problem lies with the studentId variable. Its value is too long to be stored as a standard integer so it must be stored as a bigint. When binding the parameter as an integer it simply enters '1' as the studentId value. To my understanding `bind_param` supports 4 types; integer, string, blob and double. Does anybody have any ideas as to how I could get around this problem so I can properly send the value as a bigint?

Thanks

Comment: it's because you are on a 32bit platform, switch to 64 and it will be fine.

Comment: If that's your actual code, be sure to finish those 2 first lines with semi-colons. *Just saying* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha no it's not, I actually added those lines in just as examples to save me copying in the whole doc. Thank you for parsing though ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Had to ask ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$studentId = '57004542323382'; // quotes added` and string param for binding.