# php-use "s" or "i" for long in bind_param()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

in regard to `bind_param()` function of a `prepared statement`, it is mentioned in the [php documentations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#89544) that:

> If you specify type "i" (integer), the maximum value it allows you to have is 2^32-1 or 2147483647. So, if you are using UNSIGNED INTEGER or **BIGINT** in your database, then you are better off using **"s"** (string) for this.

here it is saying we should use `s` for `big int` columns. but I tried `i` to insert a long in a big int column and it worked fine. so it confuses me! for big int should we actually use `s` or `i`?!

Comment: This is not a "documentation". You have to distinguish the documentation form *user comments*. Anyone can post anything there, and such a comment can be outdated, confused or outright wrong.

Comment: An example where `s` should be used, and not `i`, is [PHP binding 'bigint' datatype (MySQLi prepared statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908292/php-binding-bigint-datatype-mysqli-prepared-statement).  The reason is simple, and integer larger then 2^32-1 is being used (on a 32-bit version).   But no one will stop you from using `s` for values smaller than 2^32-1.

Comment: @Luuk this is what confuses me! I tested to insert a bigint with `i` and it worked. why?

Comment: Because the value you used for bigint is less than [PHP_INT_MAX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). But that value for PHP_INT_MAX depends on 32-bit or 64-bit system.  That why someone suggested to use `s`, because that will *'always'* work

Comment: I've never understood the purpose of typed bound parameters. The value range is already determined by the PHP variable that contains the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost always use `s` for everything. There are only a handful of scenarios when you would like mysqli to cast the value to the appropriate type for you. Binding everything as a string is the safest option. SQL will cast the value anyway to the type that it needs.

The comment you have found on php.net website meant that if you cast an integer string to a PHP native integer then it might overflow on 32-bit systems. PHP uses signed integers which means that the max value on a 32-bit system is only 2147483647. If you have an integer larger than this, you should use strings to prevent overflow.

Both, BIGINT (64-bit integer) and signed INT, are larger than the maximum integer on a PHP 32-bit system. However, if bind everything as a string you don't need to worry about losing any value.

Comment: Well, bigint is one of those edge cases, no? I remember testing PDO with string binding and with large values there was incorrect results.

Comment: @YourCommonSense [I can't reproduce.](https://phpize.online/?phpses=622047fb41986cbd6a5326b002bdc7a4&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57) Can you explain why would that be the case?

Comment: @Dharman one of the cases where s can't be used is for `boolean` or `tinyint(1)` columns.

Comment: @Soheil That is because when you cast a boolean false to a string then it becomes an empty string which is not a valid integer. MySQL doesn't have boolean primitives. If you want to save PHP boolean to MySQL then you need to cast it to an integer or any other appropriate value that represents True/false values in your database design.