# prevent sql injections with prepare statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working the first time with prepare statements to prevent sql injections.
I tried this code, which works fine:

```
$myInt      = "5";
$myTxt      = "Hello World";

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`myInt`, `myTxt`, `myDate`, `myBool`) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_DATE(), NULL)");
$sql->bind_param("is", $myInt, $myTxt);
```

But why it works fine?
$myInt is a string value. I set integer as bind_param type.

Can anyone explain me this situation ?

Comment: It will be treated (and cast) as an int. And prepared statements are by nature safe from SQL injections since you're not injecting the values into the query itself.

Comment: ah okay, I see. thank you :)

Comment: For what it is worth, some people recommend always binding as `s`tring - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530205/296555 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/58781505/296555

Comment: Are you asking why it accepts a string for an int value or are you asking why it prevent SQL injection?

Comment: The PHP internal code for mysqli can cast the PHP variable to its integer numeric value as it reads it. The code is here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L218